# Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to automate a specific task using python.
This task includes, among some other things, connecting with ssh to a remote server, and running a specific program (call it `prog.out`) that **may or may not ask for user input**.
After some research and after weighting my options, I decided to use Python's Paramiko (which may turned out to be wrong, considering the below...).

Let's start with the easy possibility of `prog.out` not asking any input, but rather just prints some info to console:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        printf("Hey there, fella\n");
        printf("How are you this morning?\n");
        printf("See ya...\n");

        return 0;
}
```

which compiles to: `prog.out`, and sits on *server_name*, waiting to be executed.
So in that case:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("server_name")
sin, sout, serr = client.exec_command('./prog.out')

for line in sout.readlines():
    print(line, end = '')
```

Will work perfectly fine, and will print out whatever `prog.out` produces.
But if instead `prog.out` is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        printf("Hey there, fella\n");
        printf("How are you this morning?\n");
        printf("please enter an integer...\n");
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("you entered %d\n", a);
        printf("see ya...\n");

        return 0;
}
```

then the above python code will block at `sout.readlines()` (waiting for eof?)...
The way to avoid blocking in `sout.readlines()` is to provide input to `prog.out` by writing to its stdin pipe:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("server_name")
sin, sout, serr = client.exec_command('./prog.out')

sin.write('55\n')

for line in sout.readlines():
    print(line, end = '')
```

But I can't know in advance if `prog.out` will require user's input or not...
I am looking for a robust way to run `prog.out` and let the user interact with it for as long as necessary.
Is there some indication when `prog.out` expects input?

**EDIT**

OK, I did a little experimenting, and found out that any attempt to read() from the channel will block, as long as `prog.out` has not exited, but `prog.out` can't exit as long as it wasn't provided with input...
How come I can't read bytes that were already sent by `prog.out` even when it is not finished yet?
I'd really love to simulate to the user as if he or she interacts directly with `prog.out`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library built on top of Paramiko that's perhaps better suited for your needs.

I am speaking of [python fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (of which I have no association)

> Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for
>   streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems
>   administration tasks.
>
> It provides a basic suite of operations for executing local or remote
>   shell commands (normally or via sudo) and uploading/downloading files,
>   as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user
>   for input, or aborting execution.

If I have understood your requirement correctly, your code might look something like this.

```
from fabric.api import run

@task
def run_a_out()
    run('echo "some input for a.out" | ./a.out')
```

And you would execute the remote program with

```
    fab --hosts=someserver run_a_out
```

If you wanted to dynamically controll what get's passed into a.out, you can add a parameter to `run_a_out`() and pass it from the command line.

In short Fabric provides a higher level API for paramiko with most of it's complexity hidden away.

Comment: Your choice of course but fabric authors have already done what you are trying to do

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how this lib can help my specific needs? I read its doc but couldn't figure out why this helps my problem above...

Comment: This is a really neat looking library.

Comment: OK, I looked into it some more and you are right. It's insanely easy using this library...

Comment: Glad to have been of help.