# How to pass variable from remote SSH'd machine to the host machine?

Tags: python, ssh

PS> the problem is python specific

**Background:**
So, I have 2 machines- 
Machine A- Work machine
Machine B- Remote Machine

I have a python script running on machine A, it SSH's into the remote machine and invokes a script in the remote machine using-

```
subprocess.call("ssh user@url 'python abc_script.py'")
```

I can pass variables to remote machine as follows-

```
subprocess.call("ssh user@url 'python abc_script.py var1 var2'")
```

But I also want to return a few variables from the remote machine back to the host/the machine that SSH'd into the remote

How can I do this?

One way I figured was to use Popen() or getstatusoutput()instead of call() but they return the STDOUT (all the print "" statement outputs) values

What is a good way to return 2 variables from the remote machine into the machine that SSH'd in to the remote machine?

Comment: Have you considered the HTTP protocol?

Comment: Use logging to stderr instead of `print`. Write your data to stdout, preferably in a parseble for like JSON,

Comment: @self i was looking for a simpler implementation, involving just the use of some pre-existing python function call. WIth HTTP i would have to implement socket connections and get into following the protocol. I was hoping there would be some way using SSH

Comment: Hey @KlausD.,
could you please give an example so that I can understand better!

Comment: How to use logging: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html . When you have replace all prints with logging, put your data in a list or dictionary and simply `print(json.dumps(your_data))`. Parse it on the other side with `json.loads(json_data)`

Comment: There is a much better way to do ssh with python. Check this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko/37087098#37087098 (not a duplicate so not flagging as such)