# paramiko SSHException: Channel Closed when using exec_command on an Alactel Lucent Omniswitch 6000

Tags: python, paramiko

when i run:

```
def conn_string(cmd, switch_IP, uname, pword):
 try:
     ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
     ssh.load_system_host_keys()
     ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
     ssh.connect(switch_IP, username=uname, password=pword, port=22)
     stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command=cmd, timeout=60)
     output = stdout.read()
     current_res = output.decode('ascii')
     print(current_res)
     return current_res
 except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
     print("\n Authentication Failed!")
     exit()
 except paramiko.SSHException:
     print("\n Issues with SSH service!!!")
     exit()
 except BaseException as e:
     print(str(e))
     exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
 switch_IP = input("Enter switch IP address: ")
 u_name = "abc"
 p_word = "xyz"
 res = conn_string("show configuration snapshot", switch_IP, u_name, p_word)
```

i get SSH exception: Channel Closed

but when i run:

```
    conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
    conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    conn.connect(switch_IPAddress, port=22, username=u_name,
                    password=p_word,
                    look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

    con = conn.invoke_shell()
    output = con.recv(65535)
    final_output = output.decode('ascii')
    print(final_output)

    con.send("show configuration snapshot")
    time.sleep(.5)
    output = con.recv(65535)
    final_output = output.decode('ascii')
    print(final_output)
```

it only shows me device info and the command without any output or errors

The cmd works fine on the switch console.
if I use the same code on a cisco switch(with diff command of course) it works perfect but fails on the alcatel switch. Please help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko)

Comment: i don't wanna use fabric... i want paramiko to work... what changes can i make to make it work...

Comment: is this an issue with the code or is it a n/w issue... because the same code works fine on CISCO switches...