# Scp with subprocess python with a private key

Tags: python, django, subprocess, scp

How do i get this scp command converted for python subprocess.

```
 scp -i /home/ramesh7128/Downloads/<private_key>.pem /home/ramesh7128/Downloads/testing_transfer.py <remote_add>:<remote_file_path>
```

esp the part to include the private key path is where i am having issues.

Comment: What's the issue? Usually an error message is an indicator...

Comment: There is a much better way to do this sort of thing with django: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087098/267540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're including the user on the remote machine and that you've formatted things correctly:

```
scp -i /home/ramesh7128/Downloads/<private_key>.pem /home/ramesh7128/Downloads/testing_transfer.py <remote_user>@<remote_add>:<remote_file_path>
scp -i private_key.pem /path/to/the/local/file root@server.com:/path/to/the/remote/file
```

EDIT: (from comments)

```
subprocess.Popen(["scp", "-i", "path/to/private_key.pem", myfile, destination])
```

This syntax lets Popen know about the `-i` option.

Comment: import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["scp", myfile, destination])
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question - the user part is commonly forgotten when scp troubles pop up. Looks like you need to do: subprocess.Popen(["scp", "-i", "path/to/private_key.pem", myfile, destination])  in order for Popen to know about the private key.

Comment: this worked...thanks a lot. if u could edit your answer to this, i can select this as the answer.