# Subprocess login to remote host and not coming out in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am new to python I need to execute few commands in remote host and get the output for those command

I am using below command to login and test the connection is established suscess but as soon as I entered below command it is login to remote host not coming out from the remote host. I need to enter exit command.

```
 subprocess.call('ssh host.example.com , shell=True)
```

Remote host is Linux and I am using python2.7. Passwordless login configured

What I need is

```
   subprocess.call('ssh host.example.com, shell=True)
```

If connection established. I need connection success

If connection not established. Connection failed. Please check remote host is not reachable or passwordless password not configured.

If connection success 
     verify user "dev" exist

Please advice

Comment: try [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) module

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37087098/267540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of subprocess.call method needs to be a list. Try

```
subprocess.call(["ssh","host.example.com","getent", "passwd","dev"], shell=False)
```

If the return code of `subprocess.call` is 0, the command successfully completed. 
Anything else, the command failed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Zee it worked  but How to get return code is 0 or some other.?

Comment: You can assign it to the command to a variable and then check the value of the variable, eg. 'result = subprocess.call(["ssh","host.example.com","getent", "passwd","dev"], shell=False)' - 'if result == 0: do whatever...'