# Pass argument to shell script through paramiko client.exec_command

Tags: python, bash, shell, paramiko

I want to pass argument to shell script dynamically through paramiko. I tried but I can't achieve it. If anyone knows please let me know.

Below is my code:

**Python code:**

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect("192.168.10.5", username='root', password='root')
backup_name="test_backup"
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('./backup.sh',backup_name)
stdin.write('next')
stdin.flush()
```

**Shell Script(backup.sh):**

```
#!/bin/bash

virsh snapshot-create-as one-96 "'$1'"
```

I want to create backup with the backup name mentioned in the python code through shell script. How to pass that name in *exec_command* to shell script? Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko)

Comment: `exec_command('./backup.sh %s' % backup_name)`

Comment: @whjm I got it and my issue is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments to the **exec_command**, just use the following format:

`exec_command(command, bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False, environment=None)`

For your example(**exec_command('./backup.sh',backup_name)**) you may do it this way:

`exec_command(command='./backup.sh', bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False, environment=dict(backup_name=backup_name))`

[Reference docs](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html?highlight=exec_command#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)