# Run python script over SSH

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to run a python script that will connect to SSH and continue to execute code on that server.  I can get the connection to the server with my first lines:

```
cmd = 'ssh username@host'     
os.system(cmd)
```

But any code following will wait until I am disconnected from SSH to execute. How do I continue to execute code all within one script?

Ideally, I will connect to the SSH server create a few files and copy them to my computer to do stuff with them in the same script.

I have tried Paramiko is there a way around that? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko)

Comment: There is a better way to do this. Use paramiko, or better still use Fabric, a high level library built on top of paramika. Please see the above linked answer for more

Comment: Why do you not want to use paramiko ? +1 for fabric

Comment: I can try Paramiko again.  I couldn't get it to install right.

Comment: Use a virtualenv. Should have no problem installing

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It provides a high level interface for remote control over `ssh` and they have already done all the hard work of managing authentication, keys, error handling and so on. It will be much easier than trying to run things via a system call and managing it all yourself.

More details:

- [Automate ssh connection and execution of program with Python's Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086065/automate-ssh-connection-and-execution-of-program-with-pythons-paramiko)

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the script to the remote bash.

**cat script.sh | ssh user@server /bin/bash**