# Paramiko ssh linux command excution produces no result

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, paramiko

i am trying to establish connection to a raspberrypi (named as slave in the code) connected via ethernet to a master raspberrypi. The slave raspberry pi has also an static IP address.

The following code (that is the entire code i am executing) tries to connect to the slave raspberrypi from the master raspberrypi, and issue the "echo hello" command. I have the slave connected to a screen so as far as i understand the word "hello" should be printed on the terminal.

```
import paramiko
import time

slave_ip='169.254.39.236'


def connect():
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    connect(slave_ip, username='pi', password='raspberry')
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('echo hello') 
    exit_status = ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    print (exit_status)

def main():
    connect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:    
            main()
        except:
            pass
```

**Questions:**

1- How i can tell if the login was successful? i ask this because if i provide the wrong login information or IP, the script does not crash or return errors.

2-Assuming the login was successful, why i do not see the output from the command?

Comment: consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087098/267540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't see errors because you are catching everything in your `try` statement, that's bad practice you should be catching only exceptions you want to handle
2. Your loop will run forever executing the connection over and over again, you don't want that, instead run it only once, after you know it's working do something more useful with the script
3. You are not connecting because you are recursively calling the connect function you defined, instead call `ssh_client.connect()`
4. You will not see any output un the connected display of your RPi, that is because ssh creates an independent session, if you want to see output in the connected display try the `wall` linux command, alternatively just run a command that will output some text to stdout and print it from python

A revised script would look like:

```
import paramiko
import time

slave_ip='169.254.39.236'


def connect():
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(slave_ip, username='pi', password='raspberry')
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('echo hello') 
    exit_status = ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    print(ssh_stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```