# Difficulty while using Python Paramiko to execute command on remote server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, private-key

Was trying to SSH from one linux server to another using Paramiko library but getting the

```
    import sys
    import paramiko

    hostname ="****"
    password="no password provided"
    source=""
    username="***"
    port=22

    key_file_path="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"

    #printing key
    file=open(key_file_path,"r")
    print file.read()



    try:
            ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())





 ssh.connect(hostname,port,username,password,key_filename=key_file_path,passphrase=None)
            #ssh_session=ssh.get_transport().open_session()
            stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('uptime')
            output=stdout.readlines()
            error=stderr.readlines()

            print("STDOUT output")
            print(output)
            print("output object type")
            type(output)
            print("STDERR output")
            print(error)

    except Exception, e:
            print e
            print "exception occoured"
```

Output :-

```
STDOUT output :- []
output object type :- 
STDERR output [u'Connecting to **.**.**.***:****\r\n']
```

As I am new so i have searched all over the net and have build till this point but I'm stuck at this point and not finding as to why is the error please can anyone help me.....

And also have viewed all related questions but couldn't find as to why the error is occouring...

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087098/267540

Comment: Can you execute any other command? Like `pwd`? Do you know where does the "Connecting to ..." message come from?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i tried pwd and this is the output................STDOUT output
[u'/root\n']
output object type
STDERR output
[u'Connecting to 40.87.11.133:8022\r\n']

Comment: @e4c5 referring to it will update asap.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, even with the `uptime` command.

Comment: What if you do `uptime 2>&1`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl will try and let you know

Comment: @MartinPrikryl after executing **uptime 2>&1** i'm getting this output................STDOUT output
[]
output object type
STDERR output
[u'Connecting to **.**.**.***:****\r\n']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179086/discussion-between-sandy560-and-martin-prikryl).